# Javascript Window.onbeforeunload trapping control that fired event

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an C#.NET MVC3 web app and I have a question related to the attached Stackoverflow question.  I am using a window.beforeunload event to see if there have been changes made on my View.  If so, I alert the user that they have unsaved changes.  However, if they selected the Create (submit) button, the dialog alerting the user still pops up.  I want to NOT pop up the dialog if the Create button is selected.  Any ideas?  Is there a way to see which control was clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of 2 solutions:

```
$('#submitBtn').click(function() {
    unbindOnBeforeUnload();
});

// OR

// maybe you have multiple cases where you don't want this triggered,
// so this will be better
var shouldTriggerOnBeforeUnload = true;
$('#submitBtn').click(function() {
    shouldTriggerOnBeforeUnload = false;
});
...
$(document).unload(function() {
    if (shouldTriggerOnBeforeUnload) {
        confirm();
    }
});
```

I've written it in a jQuery-like syntax, but only to keep the code concise, you can adapt it to anything you want.